# APK 25: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Location Data Type - Precise Location

Tags: declaration

I am continuously getting emails from google that app is not compliant with Google Play Policies.

[image: Here is the screenshot of the mail]

Kindly help what to do

Answer (score 0):

Most properly this is how you should answer the data safety form:

Precise location:

- Collected?    Yes
- Shared? No
- Processed ephemerally? No (or yes if you do not know who is the user when you process the location
- Required? Yes
- Purposes? App functionality